How to select the unique values in one column and group by a different column
I have a table in Oracle that has a schema as shown below
I want to get the output as shown in the result section. Any idea what the WHERE clause should look like in Oracle to get the output I need?
Table
col1_string_primary_key col2_number   col3_string              col4_timestamp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  11-11           1          str1         2024/09/04 00:00:00
                  22-22           2          str2         2024/09/04 00:01:00
                  33-33           1          str1         2024/09/04 00:02:00
                  44-44           4          str4         2024/09/04 00:03:00
                  55-55           1          str7         2024/09/04 00:04:00
                  44-44           2          str3         2024/09/04 00:04:00
                  55-55           1          str1         2024/09/04 00:00:01

Desired Query?
select 
  col2_number, col3_string
from 
  table
where 
      col4_timestamp >= to_timestamp('2024-09-04 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  AND col4_timestamp  < to_timestamp('2024-09-04 00:05:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

Desired Result
col2_number col3_string
-----------------------
          1   str1,str3
          2        str2
          4        str4


If Littlefoot's answer is what you're looking for, please edit your question and fix the expected result. If not and the result you showed is really the intended one, please explain the logic behind.

JonasMetzler, I'm not sure I understand. Both my description and @Littlefoot's answer are the same

No, the result in your question is incorrect and doesn't match your description. Compare it to Littlefoot's answer, there it is correct. That's why they write "desired result doesn't really match sample data" in their answer.

That looks like a listagg function problem, but ... desired result doesn't really match sample data because

I didn't quite get what you want simply by looking at info you posted (where clause doesn't filter anything, it returns all rows you posted), or
you forgot to actually explain rules which lead from source to target

Anyway, here's an option you might be interested in, see if it helps.
Sample data:
SQL> with test (pk, col2, col3, col4) as
  2    (select '11-11', 1, 'str1', to_date('2024/09/04 00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:Mi') from dual union all
  3     select '22-22', 2, 'str2', to_date('2024/09/04 00:01', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select '33-33', 1, 'str2', to_date('2024/09/04 00:02', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  5     select '44-44', 4, 'str4', to_date('2024/09/04 00:03', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  6     select '55-55', 1, 'str7', to_date('2024/09/04 00:04', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  7     select '44-44', 2, 'str3', to_date('2024/09/04 00:04', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  8     select '55-55', 1, 'str1', to_date('2024/09/04 00:01', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') from dual
  9    )

Query begins here:
 10  select col2, listagg(distinct col3, ', ') within group (order by col3) col3
 11  from test
 12  where col4 >= to_date('2024/09/04 00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi')
 13    and col4 <  to_date('2024/09/04 00:05', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi')
 14  group by col2;

      COL2 COL3
---------- --------------------
         1 str1, str2, str7
         2 str2, str3
         4 str4

SQL>


Thank you so much, @Littlefoot. It worked perfectly for me!

You're welcome.

@Jared Maybe you should consider accepting the answer now that it worked perfectly for you...

I don't see an option to accept the answer. I did upvote the answer. How do I accept the answer?

@Jared, documentation (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) says "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."
